# Reducing the arity of functions

Tags: programming-practices, functions

I have discovered that reducing the arity of functions in my code to zero or one improves their non-functional characteristics significantly, such as  testability, maintainability and their composability.

This must have been identified elsewhere - does this approach have a name?

Comment: [code smell](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/258400/31260)

Comment: @gnat I laughed, but surely having a large arity is a code smell. I am talking about the inverse.

Comment: [Clean Code](http://amzn.com/0132350882) has a section discussing this exact phenomenon, but doesn't give it a fancy name.  If Bob Martin didn't identify a name, I suspect it doesn't exist.

Comment: I hereby dub it `oligarity`.

Comment: @EricKing: Is excessive arity termed "vulgarity?"

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes. Brilliant.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, an arity of one is a property of a mathematical functions. The case arity=0 is really arity=1 with the parameter of `void` or `unit`. And 1 input is not the only property, but perhaps lends itself to some of the others (e.g. no side effects). Maybe your functions tend to conform to the definition of Mathematical functions?

[Here is a good article](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/mathematical-functions/) on mathematical functions (the basis for functional programming) with their benefits and drawbacks in the context of programming. Here is an excerpt.

> As you can see from the diagrams, there is always exactly one input and one output for a mathematical function. This is true for functional programming languages as well, although it may not be obvious when you first use them.

*For people scratching their heads right now, in practice in functional programming, you don't really code only single-parameter functions and nothing else. Through math trickery, you can show that an N-parameter function can be changed into N single-parameter functions with currying. (So, the compiler does that for you.)*

Maintainability probably has more to do with following DRY and SRP, since your functions are broken down into individual operations.

Composability is one of the primary strengths of math functions. I won't take time to go into all that `f(g(x))` stuff here. And I'm probably not as good at explaining it as others, so here's [another link](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/function-composition/) on that subject.

Testability is also really high with math functions since they lack side effects which have to be accounted for. By definition they also give repeatable results.

Comment: How does this relate to the OP's question about reducing arity improving maintainability, and the name of the technique so described?

Comment: I posit a reason for improved testability... that the functions might conform to mathematical functions, which are much easier to test by definition (repeatable results).

Comment: Clarified to make inference more obvious.